# What object could I have seen at late June on the Sky?

Tags: star

In around late June, I saw two star-like bodies in the sky. At first they appeared to be twinkling, but when I looked closely they appeared to change color; blue, green, a slight red, then yellow.

It freaked me out.

But I'm wondering, did I see dying stars or was it some sort of rare phenomenon occurring because of the earth's atmosphere or was it something else?

Comment: Unlikely to have seen a 'dying star' (supernova) - that would have made the news!  This question does not provide nearly enough information to get an answer - to be answered, we need an exact date and time, exact location etc.

Comment: Most probably it wasn't an astronomical thing, 1) they don't change so fast. 2) they *never* move so fast, 3) they aren't so colorful (for the human eye). I think the most probable reason could be some airplane or similar in-air moving and lighted object, but it is impossible to say any sure from so far away (both in time and space).

Comment: @Doc , it has been too long remember much..but it was around June end,2016. At night around 11pm. Seen from Kolkata, India.

Comment: @peterh they weren't moving.They were fixed! Both of them were fixed.

Comment: So is it more interesting. I still don't think it had been from astronomical source, because they aren't so colorful. What if a cloud moved before a relative strong light source, for example a street lamp?

Comment: @peterh , I am a keen observer of the sky. At night, I know some of the stars' positions and stuff. Also, the two bodies looked pretty much like stars initially. But, on closer observation, they seemed to change color. One more person witnessed it with me.

Comment: @JamilAhmed: You have given, position, date, time of the day. Good. Now we would need to know the approximate position of the objects on the sky. North/South, East/West.. Then one could check with open source programs like Stellarium.

Comment: @AtmosphericPrisonEscape East. approximately.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this does not appear to be an astronomical observation

Comment: If indeed it was a star you were looking at, it may have been a star like Capella (however, I'm not saying it was Capella). Capella is a star which is really two double-star systems, so four stars in total, and the different stars all have different colors. You can watch this star and clearly see it change colors from red to blue to white. Possibly you were looking at a similar star which was a collection of stars and the color changes were the various stars shining through, modified by atmospheric effects.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is unlikey to be astronomical in nature.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Checked on Sky Map on my phone for late June, 2016 in Kolkata - and Saturn and Antares were close to each other around then in the Eastern sky, so these may be the two objects you saw.  The colour change sounds like atmospheric effects affecting the *seeing* that night.  I don't know if June in Kolkata is particularly worse than usual for atmospheric conditions, but even on a seemingly clear night there can be a layer of turbulent air above you that will diffract the light from the sources and produce unsteady images.  This is usually worse closer to the horizon as well (as these two objects were).
Planets don't usually twinkle, so if Saturn was one of the objects, then it must have been a strong effect.
Nothing to freak out about, and keep looking up! :)